# Jquery Calculator

Tags: jquery, html, calculator

I am trying to build a HTML / Jquery calculator where a user inputs a value into a text box "Average product unit value" and then another value into "Total unit sales volume".

Once the values have been inputted I need those values to be multiplied by one another to generate a value for "Total sales value" but there is no submit button - think as soon as the user clicks outside of the text box that is when the calculation needs to happen.

[image]

If a submit button is a MUST then I am happy to but the current requirement is to not have one.

I do not know where to begin writing the logic to be able to do this - I am a novice when it comes to Jquery as I am still learning it.

[image]

here is the code to help

All suggestions are welcome - hope the image helps

Jordy

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/blur/ (and I can't help but wonder.... homework?)

Comment: @Jordy Updated my answer to demonstrate usage with your HTML :)

Comment: maybe you can use this plugin https://github.com/xsanisty/jquery-calx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basics. I'm sure you can finish it from here, but if not, post your HTML and the formula you want to use.

**EDIT:** Updated to use your HTML.

[Working example available](http://jsfiddle.net/PWAJA/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').change(function()
    {
        var answer = parseInt($('#product-unit-val').val()) * parseInt($('#total-unit-sales').val()) * parseInt($('#number-reps').val());
        $('#sales-val').html('$' + answer);
    });
});
```

Comment: Joe you are absolutely nearly there - just #number-reps does not need to be included in the calculation it's only #product-unit-val and #number-reps - is it possible to use multiplication as currently it's adding the values 

Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @Jordy Quote: `#number-reps does not need to be included`, Quote: `only #product-unit-val and #number-reps` - which two do you want? :P

Comment: Hah ok the only two that needs to be calculated in this instance is #product-unit-val and #total-unit-sales - the end value once gone through calculation generates the figure for #sales-val.

Comment: @Jordy http://jsfiddle.net/PWAJA/2/ - made it very easy for you to tweak to how you want :)

Comment: Perfect thank you very much Joe! I do have another question... if I want to do this for other inputs for example I want to multiply #number-reps and #extra-units to generate a value for #total-extra-units do I just repeat what you have done in the jquery? would you mind please showing me again in jsfiddle how you would execute this for two calculations - eventually I need about 4 or so done I just need to see how it's done for two instances then I'm away :-)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the HTML:

```
Average product unit value <input type="text" id="product-unit-val" /><br/>
Total unit sales value <input type="text" id="total-unit-sales" /><br/>
Number of reps <input type="text" id="number-reps" /><br/>
Total sales value <span id="sales-val"></span>$
```

This is the jquery that makes the magic:

```
$(function() {
  $('#product-unit-val, #total-unit-sales, #number-reps').change(function() {
   var total = parseInt($("#product-unit-val").val()) *  parseInt($("#total-unit-sales").val()) * parseInt($("#number-reps").val());
   if (!isNaN(total)) {
      $("#sales-val").html(total);
   }
  });
});
```

The first line executes the code only after initialization. Second line:

```
$('#product-unit-val, #total-unit-sales, #number-reps').change(function() {
```

says that next function will be executed if something changes. Next line is the operation: parseInt is not absolutly necessary, but it is useful sometimes (use parseFloat if your values are float). Lines like $("#ID").val() says: give me the value of this ID item. I've added a NaN (Not a Number) test to avoid bad results when not all values are set.

Note also that your calculator responds every time user *changes* an input box, it is the user should do a click outside the input. If you want that your calculator runs on each key change the line:

```
  $('#product-unit-val, #total-unit-sales, #number-reps').change(function() {
```

by

```
  $('#product-unit-val, #total-unit-sales, #number-reps').keyup(function() {
```

There is a [working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/aCG7d/1/).

Comment: Hi Ivan - thank you very much for your explained answer but the jquery didn't work :-(

Comment: Sorry, code has been corrected. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/aCG7d/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery's .change method?

```
$(".input").change(function (){
//check if both have data
//do the calculation
//save the value
});
```

Anytime an input field changes, this event will fire

Answer (score 0):

Just attach an `onChange` to each of the textboxes that calls your function that retrieves and multiplies the values and updates the total. The function should screen for bad input.

Answer (score 0):

I would attach a onkeyup and onblur event handler to the various text fields.  On those events, call your function that does the simple math and outputs the value to the final text box.  Make sure you take care to take care of bad input which will result in a NaN output